# How to add custom data (text) in to protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-report

Tags: angularjs, automation, jasmine, report, protractor

What is the easiest way to add console.log (data) to final report from the protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-report ?

Comment: Any luck Alex? I am looking for the same

Comment: ended up with standard reporting. Thanks for asking